# Exclude all sub category posts from array including only main category

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I did a custom short code to get the posts list from the current category page (the posts are a custom post type for site projects):

- Main category, 10 items (i'm on this page)

  - Sub category, 25 items

I need to show only the 10 main category items and not the sub category items.

How can i edit my function?

```html
// GET THE CURR£NT CATEGORY SLUG
    $categories = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'pj-categs');
    foreach( $categories as $category ) {
        $categorySlug = $category->slug;
        echo $categorySlug;
    }


    // EXTRACT THE POSTS
    $the_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'pj-categs'      => $categorySlug,
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'post__not_in'   => [get_the_ID()]

    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution to avoid showing subcategories .get_the_terms() return WP_Term Object.This object has a parent property. first, check $category->parent == 0 if you find true then store data in a variable.